# ie7 killing list-style on floated ul's

Tags: css

I have two ul's (.listone and .listtwo respectfully) floated left and the other right. The list-style:circle; works in every browser except for ie7 =< . In ie7 the list-style is just ignored. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try `list-style-type` as the `list-style` is the shorthand for all subproperties.

Although the most likely problem, is that with floating the the the circles might be hidding behind the adjacent elements.. try giving your `ul` margin/padding to see if they appear..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stick to `<ul type="circle">`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
list-style-position:inside;
```

IE7 is most likely considering the list markers below the z-index of the list items themselves or bounding elements, but if the list markers are inside the list items their display should be forced.